# Refactoring switch statement containing methods with no parameters

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, refactoring

I'm currently refactoring my code and got blocked. I have a `switch` statement that I just know that can be refactored, I just have lack of experience to do so :( Most of patterns and ways of dealing with switches focus of managing parameters which differs methods, but it's not the case here. Any ideas what can I do about it? Would really appreciate any hints.

```
public void manageMenuAction(MenuItem item, GiftListPresenterViewConnector activityConnector) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_your_account:
            activityConnector.goToEditAccount();
            break;
        case R.id.help:
            activityConnector.goToHelpScreen();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about:
            createInfoDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_exit:
            activityConnector.exitApp();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            clearLocalData();
            activityConnector.logout();
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm coding for Android, so working with java 1.7. `GiftListPresenterViewConnector` is an interface.

Comment: This looks like a perfectly valid `switch` statement.  Why do you want to refactor it?

Comment: How do you call the method?

Comment: This is pretty much the simplest way to do things.  Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Colleague pointed it seems too long and I'm in refactor trance right now too (I like cleaning things up :( ) so every switch with more than 3 cases seems a bit "off" to me. Anyway, you think I shouldn't touch it?

Comment: No.  I totally agree with cleaning things up, but having 5 options in a switch statement is not excessive.  In fact 3 is the minimum (if you have 2 you should use an if ), so 5 is barely more than that.  YOur only options for replacement are long else if statements which are harder to read, or a solution with an interface and 5 subclassses minimum to use an object oriented approach, which is super over complicated for this.

Comment: @Andy Turner which one? manageMenuAction? I go from onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) in Activity through presenter to external utils class. GiftListPresenterViewConnector is an interface connecting presenter and view.

Gabe Sechan yeah, if else is not an option here, and subclasses seems pointless in my opinion also. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Hint: for working code, codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, some people say that in good OO designs, switch statements are never perfectly valid. Because good OO avoids them; for example using polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you could implement a generic `MenuItem.id` behavior when a `MenuItem` holds this generic instance and when getting into `manageMenuAction` just invoke `MenuItem.getItemId().executeBehavior()`.

(You could also make a generic `MenuItem` instead of holding a generic instance of the `id`)

Honestly, i would not do that since this `id` is probably just a simple `Integer` and a switch case would probably be the most simplified way to do it

Comment: Yeah, tbh I'm not feeling strong enough to rummage through native android methods :D

Comment: hehe i know what you mean, tell me what you decided to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using 'command' design pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: Wouldn't it require me to create 5 additional classes just to get rid off one switch statement?

Comment: @Reiz3N Perhaps it would, but it might be less painful than you might think.  The classes would only have to differ, at least at first, with regard to the action method which the command would be invoking.

Comment: the point is that you can do some action not only from menu, but from any other place. You use mvp, so maybe you should not use ui - specific id constants not inside view.

Answer (score 0):

The item which stands out to me is `createInfoDialog`, because it's the only path which doesn't go through `activityConnector`.  If you were to make that a method of `GiftListPresenterViewConnector`, then this whole method could be moved into that class and would not need to take it as an argument.  But I agree with other commenters; this method looks fine.

Comment: Yeah, I could move createInfoDialog, even thought about it. But moving whole switch statement to GiftListPresenterViewConnector which is interface implemented by my activity is not an option, it has to be in presenter (main purpose of MVP is to extract that logic from view) :( Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

The one other option way I see: you could be using a Map.

1. **key** would be your item IDs
2. **values** would be some generic callback object

Then you could write code like

```
callbacks.get(item.getItemId()).doCallback();
```

But that also seems a bit "far-fetched"; and probably isn't very much "android style" of doing things.