# How to verify number of call of private method in public method in Junit?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, private-methods, public-method

```
public void publicMethod() {
  for (i=1;i<10;i++)
    privateMethod();
}

private privateMethod() {
    something...
}
```

I need to write a JUnit testcase to verify the number of times the `privateMethod()` is called.

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't do that. You don't write unit tests to verify **implementation** details.

Your tests make sure that your **public** methods fulfill their contract. So you assert that things returned are as expected; or that subsequent calls to other methods give the desired output. Or you *expect* calls to throw specified exceptions. Or, third option: you injected *mocked* objects; which you later on *verify* that the mocks saw the method calls you specified upfront.

But writing test cases to specifically test private methods is really bad practice!

Comment: should be the accepted answer. private methods are not what your class provides to the users of it, it the way it implements what it provides.

Comment: oh what a shame :)

Comment: Hope you'll get it, hopefully one day ill grow up and be as good as you are

Comment: Sure. Just keep going. And I see: I already helped you today with some upvotes; like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392907/refactoring-switch-statement-containing-methods-with-no-parameters/39393012#39393012 ...

Comment: Oh that was you ♥